# C++11 auto /I dont understand something

Tags: c++, c++11

Ok. this is my code :

```
CShop::~CShop()
{
    TPacketGCShop pack;
    pack.header = HEADER_GC_SHOP;
    pack.subheader  = SHOP_SUBHEADER_GC_END;
    pack.size = sizeof(TPacketGCShop);
    Broadcast(&pack, sizeof(pack));
    GuestMapType::iterator it;
    it = m_map_guest.begin();
    while (it != m_map_guest.end())
    {
        LPCHARACTER ch = it->first;
        ch->SetShop(NULL);
        ++it;
    }
    M2_DELETE(m_pGrid);
}
```

Soo i have `GuestMapType::iterator it;` and this `it = m_map_guest.begin();`

It'f fine if i make my function like this?

```
CShop::~CShop()
{
    TPacketGCShop pack;
    pack.header = HEADER_GC_SHOP;
    pack.subheader  = SHOP_SUBHEADER_GC_END;
    pack.size = sizeof(TPacketGCShop);
    Broadcast(&pack, sizeof(pack));

    auto it = m_map_guest.begin();
    while (it != m_map_guest.end())
    {
        LPCHARACTER ch = it->first;
        ch->SetShop(NULL);
        ++it;
    }
    M2_DELETE(m_pGrid);
}
```

I removed GuestMapType::iterator it;  to simplify my code?
My question is. Affect this my program?  Any risk ?

Comment: That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's perfectly fine and declaring iterators with `auto` is, from my view, a good practice for at least two reasons:

1- Generally, iterator's type are pretty long to type. The less you type, the less you mis-type. It makes the code clearer too, because you hide an *implementation detail* that doesn't really matter, in that context.

2- *Forward compatibility*: when you will modify your code, i.e. the name for the iterator type name, you won't have to change the code where you use it with `auto`. After all, you want to use **that type of iterator**, independently from its name.

Comment: Thank you!  C++11 awesome. :))

Comment: Another question. Please.  auto can prevent memory leak ?

Comment: @Joe.Dc No, it doesn't. If you want to prevent memory leaks, learn about [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) and [smart pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one). You may also give a look to the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines), a brand new project started by Stroustrup, Sutter and others to change the way C++ is taught and used.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the return type of `m_map_guest.begin()` can be determined to be `GuestMapType::iterator`, there should be no difference.

The `auto` typing is not some magical dynamic/weak type, it's simply an indicator to the compiler that it should work out the ***strong*** type itself, without you being explicit about it<sup>1</sup>. There is ***no*** functional difference between the two lines:

```
int i = 7;
auto i = 7;
```

because the compiler uses the type of the `7` in the second example to infer the actual type of `i`.

You should generally use `auto` wherever possible for the same reason you should use the second of these in C:

```
ttype *x = malloc(sizeof (ttype));
ttype *x = malloc(sizeof (*x));
```

The latter requires only *one* change if the type ever changes to something else - that becomes much more important with `auto` as the actual type and declaration can be much more widely separated.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, where the return type is *different,* such as implicit conversions or sub-classes, it's a little harder for the compiler to work out what type you want. So it may not work in those cases.